# Regex - negative look-ahead assertion

Tags: php, regex

I wand to replace URLs like www.example.com/profile/USERNAME by [user]USERNAME[/user] BBCode!

```
$userURLSearch  = "#((https?|ftp)://|www\.)example\.com/profile/([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_-]+)(?!/)#i";
$userURLReplace = "[user]\\3[/user]";
$text = preg_replace($userURLSearch, $userURLReplace, $text);
```

But it also transforms URLs like www.example.com/profile/USERNAME/more/and/more into [user]USERNAME[/user]/more/and/more ... :(
It should only transform exactly "/profile/USERNAME".

can somebody help me?
thx

Answer (score 1):

Replace (?!/) by $ at the end?

Comment: That would only match urls that end the string.  `$text` could contain many URLs that need to be replaced...

Comment: Oh right, I didn't appreciate that. So you want it followed by a non-word char that isn't '/'? Would putting \b in before the (?!/) do it?